# How do I sort a Binary Search Tree from greatest to least?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I need to return an array of nodes sorted from high to low. At the moment I am trying to implement an inorder traversal which gives me the exact opposite of what I'm looking for.

The tree looks like:

```
                 10. Captain Picard
                 /                  \
          6. Commander Riker       11. Commander Data
            /         \               \
    4. Lt. Cmdr.   7. Lt. Cmdr.     12. Lt. Cmdr.
        Worf           LaForge           Crusher
             \                           \
        5. Lieutenant                  13. Lieutenant
        security-officer                    Selar
```

My function looks like:

```
listOfficersByExperience(officerNames = []) {
    if (this.leftReport) {
      officerNames = this.leftReport.listOfficersByExperience(officerNames);
    }

    officerNames.push(this.officerName);

    if (this.rightReport) {
      officerNames = this.rightReport.listOfficersByExperience(officerNames);
    }

    return officerNames;
}
```

From this, I receive:

```
[
  'Lt. Cmdr. Worf',
  'Lieutenant Security-Officer',
  'Commander Riker',
  'Lt. Cmdr. LaForge',
  'Captain Picard',
  'Commander Data',
  'Lt. Cmdr. Crusher',
  'Lieutenant Selar'
]
```

When I need to receive:

```
[
  'Lieutenant Selar',
  'Lt. Cmdr. Crusher',
  'Commander Data',
  'Captain Picard',
  'Lt. Cmdr. LaForge',
  'Commander Riker',
  'Lieutenant Security-Officer',
  'Lt. Cmdr. Worf'
]
```

Is there a way that I can reverse these nodes or is there a different sorting method that I need/should implement?

Comment: A simple bubble-sort is all you need. Why a btree? Is that how the data is currently stored? This is as simple as `arr.sort((a,b)=>b - a);`

Comment: @RandyCasburn Bubble sort shouldn't be used for any purpose except learning about sorting algorithms.

Comment: @kaya3 - Array.prototype.sort() implements a bubble sort - my suggestion was to use that, as my comment states. Even with that in mind, a btree is the wrong instrument here unless the OP was instructed to do so.

Comment: @RandyCasburn No, it implements a sorting algorithm, you generally don't need to know which sorting algorithm, and I don't know of any implementation which uses bubble sort. Also, the question says nothing about the use-case so I don't know why you think a BST is the wrong thing to use, unless you think a BST is always the wrong thing to use regardless of use-case; there are plenty of problems where a BST will give better performance than an array that you have to sort every time you insert a new element.

Comment: @kaya3 - yes, my generalization was too broad, and incorrect. I don't dislike BST. While my opinion is irrelevant, the pragmatic approach of using `.sort()` is what appeals to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just swap the two `if` statements where you make a recursive call, so that you first visit `rightReport` and then later `leftReport`.

```
listOfficersByExperience(officerNames = []) {
    if (this.rightReport) {
      officerNames = this.rightReport.listOfficersByExperience(officerNames);
    }

    officerNames.push(this.officerName);

    if (this.leftReport) {
      officerNames = this.leftReport.listOfficersByExperience(officerNames);
    }

    return officerNames;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is it.. I was trying to implement various methods but didn't think to switch this if statements.. thank you!